# Verb: abbreviation stand for/ are used for

Tags: british-english, abbreviations

I am working on my reseach project and in a tabelle I used abbreviation. After the tabelle i want to explain them.

How to explain it?

1. in tabelle , the following abbreviation stand for: A is ..., B is ...
2. in tabelle , the following abbreviation are used  for: A is ..., B is ...

Comment: *Table* needs a determiner of some sort ("In the table..., in this table...) and *stand for* is [not used in that way](https://www.lexico.com/definition/stand_for); neither is *used for*. I think our sister site will be able to explain things better.

Comment: "In the table, the following abbreviations are used: A = ..., B = ..."